# remove rows from data table using LINQ

Tags: linq, datatable, asp.net-3.5

I have a data table with a date column in it (RequestDate).
I need to remove all rows where value in the RequestDate column is older than 30 days, using Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to find rows that should be deleted:

```
var rowsToDelete = source.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(r => DateTime.Now - r.Field<DateTime>("RequestDate") > TimeSpan.FromDays(30))
                         .ToList();
```

But still need `foreach` loop to delete the rows from source `DataTable`:

```
foreach(var row in rowsToDelete)
    source.Remove(row);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => DateTime.Now.Date - r.Field<DateTime>("RequestDate").Date > TimeSpan.FromDays(30))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r => r.Delete());
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Solution here:

```
Dim rows As DataRow() = (From anyNamehere In yourTableName.AsEnumerable().Cast(Of DataRow)() Where anyNamehere .Field(Of Integer)("id") = 1).ToArray()
                    For Each row As DataRow In rows
                        yourTableName.Rows.Remove(row)
```